# Core dump while running 'rake rails:update:bin' during Rails 4 upgrade

Tags: rake, bundler, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm upgrading an existing Rails 3.2 application to Rails 4. I'm using ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-linux] through rbenv, on Ubuntu 13.04. I was using the '--binstubs' option with Rails 3.2. During the upgrade, I:

- upgraded Rails to Rails 4.0.0
- upgraded the Gemfile with the latest Rails 4 equivalent gems
- ran 'bundle config --delete bin && rm -rf bin'

Running 'rake rails:update:bin' core dumps with the top few lines being:

```
/home/user/projects/proj_name/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0039 p:---- s:0128 b:0128 l:000127 d:000127 CFUNC  :require
c:0038 p:0010 s:0124 b:0124 l:000116 d:000123 BLOCK  /home/user/projects/proj_name/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228
c:0037 p:0071 s:0122 b:0122 l:000121 d:000121 METHOD /home/user/projects/proj_name/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213
/home/user/projects/proj_name/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-linux]
```

Given the size of the Gem and error output, I have created a gist at https://gist.github.com/grcarey/6109181, that contains the Gemfile and the output from the rake command.

Some ideas on solving this would be greatly appreciated.

---------- Update -----------

Running the command with 'ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux]' gives the following few lines in the error output:

```
-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0039 p:---- s:0128 b:0128 l:000127 d:000127 CFUNC  :require
c:0038 p:0010 s:0124 b:0124 l:000116 d:000123 BLOCK  /home/user/projects/proj_name/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228
c:0037 p:0071 s:0122 b:0122 l:000121 d:000121 METHOD /home/user/projects/proj_name/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213
c:0036 p:0019 s:0117 b:0117 l:000116 d:000116 METHOD /home/user/projects/proj_name/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228
c:0035 p:0011 s:0112 b:0112 l:000111 d:000111 TOP    /home/user/projects/proj_name/.bundle/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/lib/nokogiri/xml.rb:1
c:0034 p:---- s:0110 b:0110 l:000109 d:000109 FINISH
Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux]
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved.

I had been using the bundle binstubs option in Rails 3.2 and I hadn't deleted the project's bundle and bin dirs prior to the upgrade.

After deleting these dirs and re-running `bundle install`, then running `rake rails:update:bin` the problem was solved.